# robo3t not invoking browser authentication for cloudflare

Tags: mongodb, ssh, cloudflare, robo3t, mongodb-compass

I'm using Cloudflare access to authenticate my MongoDB server(using an SSH tunnel) but Robo3T not invoking browser authentication while using Cloudflare DNS with Robo3T SSH configuration(creating a tunnel through a bastion host to access the mongodb server).

But if I'm using bastion server IP instead of DNS i.e. bypassing Cloudflare access authentication, it works perfectly fine.

I'm facing the same issue with the MongoDB-compass as well.

Any help is really appreciated.